# How Can I Set Manually Weights and Biases of a Convolotional Neural Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I have defined some layers and I want to set manually weights and biases of this network.
for this purpose, I wrote a code in Matlab as shown below :

```
%% Defining Layers
layers = [imageInputLayer([28 28 1],'Normalization','none');
convolution2dLayer(5,20);
reluLayer();
maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2);
fullyConnectedLayer(10);
softmaxLayer();];
%% Set Manually Weights and Biases
layers(2,1).Weights = Conv1_Weights ;
layers(2,1).Bias = CONV1_Biases  ;
layers(5,1).Weights = FC1_Weights ;
layers(5,1).Bias = FC2_Bias ;
net = SeriesNetwork(layers);
%% 
X = imread(____)
X_Single = single(X);
X_Single_Normalize = (X_Single-min(X_Single(:)))/(max(X_Single(:))-min(X_Single(:)));
F1 = activations(net,X_Single_Normalize,2,'OutputAs','channels'); 
F2 = activations(net,X_Single_Normalize,3,'OutputAs','channels'); 
F3 = activations(net,X_Single_Normalize,4,'OutputAs','channels'); 
F4 = activations(net,X_Single_Normalize,5,'OutputAs','channels');
```

Actually, I have received this Error :

```
Error using nnet.internal.cnn.layer.FullyConnected/forwardPropagateSize  (line 101)
An input size for the layer must be defined in order to call forwardPropagateSize.

Error in SeriesNetwork>iDetermineLayerOutputSize (line 952)
inputSize = layers{i}.forwardPropagateSize(inputSize);

Error in SeriesNetwork/activations (line 775)
            outputSize = iDetermineLayerOutputSize(this.PrivateNetwork.Layers,
            layerID, inputSize );

Error in untitled1 (line 21)
F4 = activations(net,X_Single_Normalize,5,'OutputAs','channels');
```

Can anyone help me about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that as of R2017b, SeriesNetwork in NNT currently doesn't "finalize" the network to make it ready for inference.

You can simplify the repro steps to:

```
>> layers = [imageInputLayer([28 28 1],'Normalization','none');
convolution2dLayer(5,20);
reluLayer();
maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2);
fullyConnectedLayer(10);
softmaxLayer();];
>>
>> net = SeriesNetwork(layers);
>> 
>> A = rand(28,28);

>> activations(net,A,5);
```

As a workaround, you need to use **trainNetwork** to at least train for one iteration. The resulting network should be ready for training/inference. You can set the Learning Rate on each layer with learnable parameters to avoid the training actually doing any update to your weight initializations.

```
function example

layers = [imageInputLayer([28 28 1],'Normalization','none'),...
convolution2dLayer(5,20),...
reluLayer(),...
maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2),...
fullyConnectedLayer(10),...
softmaxLayer(),...
classificationLayer];

A = rand(28,28);

net = constructInitializedNetwork(layers);
activations(net,A,5);

function net = constructInitializedNetwork(layers)

X = rand(28,28);
Y = categorical(1,1:10);

layers = freezeLayers(layers);
options = 
trainingOptions('sgdm','MaxEpochs',1,'InitialLearnRate',eps);
net = trainNetwork(X,Y,layers,options);


function layers = freezeLayers(layers)

for idx = 1:length(layers)
    if isprop(layers(idx),'WeightLearnRateFactor')
       layers(idx).WeightLearnRateFactor = 0;
    end

    if isprop(layers(idx),'BiasLearnRateFactor')
       layers(idx).BiasLearnRateFactor = 0; 
    end
end
```

Comment: Well, at first I have trained this model by using trainNetwork and then I decided to set manually weights and biases but this has returned this error to me :  {  You cannot set the read-only property 'Layers' of SeriesNetwork.}

Comment: Right, but the point I was making was that you can’t use the SeriesNetwork constructor directly and get a model that is ready for inference (activations). The trainNetwork Interface is currently the only want to get a “complete” SeriesNetwork object.

Comment: Is there any solotion for this problem ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully it makes what I was suggesting more clear.

Comment: Thank you Very Much Alex, Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if this helped you?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the delay.